# Cant get a virtual host running on Ubuntu 17.10 with apache

Tags: ubuntu, apache2

maybe just a small fail.

I am moving from Windows to Linux with PHP development stuff and cannot get my v-hosts running. I did it in the same way as done on my windows machines and older Linux machines. But it does not work.

This is the way I did:

Host file permissions

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 232 Apr 14 10:03 /etc/hosts
```

Hosts file content

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   ubuntu.dev  ubuntu

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

content of /etc/apache2/sites-available

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Apr 21 17:44 .
drwxr-xr-x 8 root root 4096 Apr 21 17:19 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1332 Jul 27  2017 000-default.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 6338 Jul 27  2017 default-ssl.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  480 Apr 21 17:43 ubuntu.dev.conf
```

content of /etc/apache2/sites-available/ubuntu.dev.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin mail@mymail.de
        ServerName ubuntu.dev
        ServerAlias www.ubuntu.dev
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        <Directory /var/www/html/>
                DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

content of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Apr 21 17:43 .
drwxr-xr-x 8 root root 4096 Apr 21 17:19 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   35 Apr 21 17:19 000-default.conf -> ../sites-available/000-default.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   34 Apr 21 17:41 ubuntu.dev.conf -> ../sites-available/ubuntu.dev.conf
```

content of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ubuntu.dev.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin mail@mymail.de
        ServerName ubuntu.dev
        ServerAlias www.ubuntu.dev
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        <Directory /var/www/html/>
                DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Do you have any hints vor me?

Regards n00n....

Edit File #1 - access.log

```
::1 - - [21/Apr/2018:17:34:22 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3477 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [21/Apr/2018:17:34:22 +0200] "GET /icons/ubuntu-logo.png HTTP/1.1" 200 3623 "http://localhost/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [21/Apr/2018:17:34:22 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 500 "http://localhost/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [21/Apr/2018:17:51:53 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3477 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.117 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [21/Apr/2018:17:51:53 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 500 "http://localhost/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.117 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [22/Apr/2018:09:50:46 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3477 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.117 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [22/Apr/2018:09:50:46 +0200] "GET /icons/ubuntu-logo.png HTTP/1.1" 304 180 "http://localhost/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.117 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [22/Apr/2018:09:50:46 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 500 "http://localhost/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.117 Safari/537.36"
```

Edit File #2: error.log

```
[Sat Apr 21 17:19:34.406581 2018] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 22619:tid 139673765931968] AH00489: Apache/2.4.27 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Apr 21 17:19:34.406753 2018] [core:notice] [pid 22619:tid 139673765931968] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sat Apr 21 17:19:48.671535 2018] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 22619:tid 139673765931968] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sat Apr 21 17:19:48.737337 2018] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 22828:tid 140270657166272] AH00489: Apache/2.4.27 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Apr 21 17:19:48.737543 2018] [core:notice] [pid 22828:tid 140270657166272] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sat Apr 21 17:22:55.285086 2018] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 22828:tid 140270657166272] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sat Apr 21 17:22:55.344240 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 31501] AH00163: Apache/2.4.27 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Apr 21 17:22:55.344386 2018] [core:notice] [pid 31501] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sat Apr 21 17:22:55.717155 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 31501] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sat Apr 21 17:22:55.811931 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 31558] AH00163: Apache/2.4.27 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Apr 21 17:22:55.811997 2018] [core:notice] [pid 31558] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sat Apr 21 17:26:24.073839 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 31558] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sat Apr 21 17:26:24.184819 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 31945] AH00163: Apache/2.4.27 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Apr 21 17:26:24.184887 2018] [core:notice] [pid 31945] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sat Apr 21 17:30:29.517890 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 31945] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
[Sat Apr 21 17:30:29.564761 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 31945] AH00163: Apache/2.4.27 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Apr 21 17:30:29.564782 2018] [core:notice] [pid 31945] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sat Apr 21 17:42:12.205460 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 31945] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
[Sat Apr 21 17:42:12.250360 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 31945] AH00163: Apache/2.4.27 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Apr 21 17:42:12.250383 2018] [core:notice] [pid 31945] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sat Apr 21 17:43:04.967366 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 31945] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sat Apr 21 17:43:05.073899 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 6355] AH00163: Apache/2.4.27 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Apr 21 17:43:05.073966 2018] [core:notice] [pid 6355] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sat Apr 21 17:49:23.855978 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 6355] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sat Apr 21 17:51:18.491458 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 849] AH00163: Apache/2.4.27 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Apr 21 17:51:18.491694 2018] [core:notice] [pid 849] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sat Apr 21 17:59:39.110292 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 849] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sun Apr 22 09:46:16.682729 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 920] AH00163: Apache/2.4.27 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Apr 22 09:46:16.683120 2018] [core:notice] [pid 920] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

Comment: Did you run sudo service apache2 restart?

Comment: yes, I did... did it more than once...

Comment: kannst du mal gucken ob /var/log/apache2/error.log was hergibt. Hast du die ganzen Pakete installiert die du für php + apache brauchst?

Comment: @baao Hab error.log & access.log im Edit hinzugefügt. Beide sehen mir unscheinbar aus. Wie prüfe ich ob die alle Pakete vorhanden sind? Sorry, hab das gleiche Problem auch an einem anderen Rechner und Linux ist neu für mich. 

Sorry to all others, but I got an answer in german which let me reply in german.

Comment: I'll switch back to english so that others will understand too.. If you try to access the server via it's ip, what happens then?

Comment: thx for english... I access it locally, its only a dev machine. I is available by localhost, but... OMG.... Think forgot to create the VHOSTS folder... lol

Comment: @baao Fixed it, but still same. Mysterious, I enter http:// in my browser (ubuntu) and it replaces it by https://... On chrome and firefox. Maybe its time to say good bye to http and only use https.